# jQuery animate to offset/position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery animate to change the position of an element:

`$('#item').animate({'top' : '-50'}, 0);`

I don't need the animation, I just want to set the position.  I tried both `offset` and `position`, but neither seemed to work right.

How should update this to not use animate?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
$('#item').css({'top' : '-50'});
```